# Bootstrap Grid - Navigation Bar - Border issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have tried margins/padding/border options in every way and I cannot remove this white space from the end of my navbar. Does anyone have a simple solution please? Image is attached detailing exact issue. Thanks.

[image]

```
HTML:

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="list-inline clearfix">
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 ul-menu-color menuitem">
                    <a href="index.html" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><i class="fa fa-home" san-serif hidden="true"></i><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 ul-menu-color menuitem">
                    <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><i class="fa fa-ticket" aria hidden="true"></i><span>Tickets</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 ul-menu-color menuitem">
                    <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria hidden="true"></i><span>Video</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 ul-menu-color menuitem">
                    <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria hidden="true"></i><span>Contact</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

CSS:

.menuitem{
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    }

.menuitem a{
        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        height: 120px;
    }

.menuitem a i{
    padding-top: 22px;
    display: block;
    color: #fafafa;
    font-size: 26px;
    }

    .ul-menu-color{
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: 'Creepster', cursive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have enclosed your navbar inside of div element. And then you are defining  new div element. Div is a block level element and that is why you are observing a white space which is a default margin between two block level elements. Try enclosing them either in one parent div or you can do following,

For the div after the navbar, use css as,

`div{
margin-top: -10px;
}`

I hope this will work

Comment: Hi Usman, do you mean instead of using the 2 divs :<div class="container-fluid"> and <div class="row". I put just 1 <div class="container-fluid row" ? As I tried it with one div too and the border still exists. thanks.

Comment: After trying everything - I am just going to remove the "list-inline clearfix" for now. Its results in no space under the navbar. It causes another issue but I may find it easier to fix that issue instead!!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this issue, it was due to class="list-inline clearfix"

I removed and added padding to the UL and the navbar is now perfect.